# java focus on other application

Tags: java, runtime, awtrobot

From my Java application I try to give the focus on another open application in Windows and then send some KeyEvents.
Everything works fine until a second window is opened (due to the KeyEvents I sent and is normal expected behaviour) in the mentioned application. When this second window opens the next KeyEvents in my code areno longer executed. Any help?

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RobotANB {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException {

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("[path to EXE]");

        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.delay(20);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.delay(20);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.delay(20);

        // S
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.delay(20);

        // Second window in other application opens here
        // Code below no longer executed and should be
        // executed in the second window

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.delay(20);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.delay(20);            

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a delay of 1000 solved the issue

```
...
// S
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.delay(20);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.delay(1000);

// Second window in other application opens here
// Code below no longer executed and should be
// executed in the second window

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.delay(20);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.delay(20);
...
```